# AJAX call not rendering my partial rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am  trying to get an Ajax call working in rails, not quite sure what im doing wrong

So in my index I have a form that calls an api then returns the result to the results path. so what i want to do is to get the results rendered on the index page

What i have so far is

Controller

```
def index

end

def results
 results = contact_search(params[:search])
 @results = results
end
```

Index

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
   <h2>Search for a contact</h2>
    <%= form_tag  results_path,  :method => "get", :remote => true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder => "Enter Email Address here...." %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' , :id => "submitForm" %>
   <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
 <div class="cResults">

     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Partial _contactResults.html.erb

```
<h1>The Results</h1>
 <%= @results["contactInfo"]["familyName"] %><br>
 <img src= <%= @results["photos"].first["url"] %> />
```

Index.js.erb

```
$('.cResults').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'contactResults') %>");
```

Am i missing anything?

Comment: I think the js file should be `results.js.erb`, why? Because `index.js.erb` is "executed" when the controller receives a JS format request on `index action`.

Comment: yeah that worked, so the rule is to create a js.erb file for the view you want to pull in via Ajax?

Comment: would you like to put that as answer, i will happily accept

Comment: I just posted an answer with alittle bit more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript file should be named as the action that "computed" the results:

```
# in results.js.erb, not index.js.erb
$('.cResults').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'contactResults') %>");
```

If you need to execute Javascript for a controller's action, you can name the file as the action, with `.js.erb` instead of common `.html.erb`. This file will be executed when the controller receive a request for this action, interpreted as JS.